# How could I do the attach effect, when you select the Send by Mail option in Photos App

Tags: iphone, email, photos

How could I do the attach effect, when you select the Send by Mail option in Photos App, that when the background turns dark, the mail app is open and the image is attached to the mail body.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether CocoaTouch provides a direct API for that. Building it by hand you would probably have to

1. transform the image or media you would like to attach to a smaller frame
2. call the Mail API to get the modal Compose View, but keeping your image in the foreground
3. attach the file to the message via the standard API
4. find out where Mail puts the image in the mail body
5. create an animation that looks like it's being placed into the body